# Call a function when data is transfered to php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am here to ask that is there any settings argument in jQuery ajax() which let us to call a function when data has transferred to php file successfully not when the data has transferred and php file parsed the code and returned a value.

I have following code:

```
$.ajax({
    ..
    ..
    ..
    success: function(data) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

But I want it like:

```
$.ajax({
    ..
    ..
    ..
    onTransfer: function() {
        // do something like show a div saying "Done".
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You only get 1 answer from server side, what's wrong with success? If your process takes too long then you could return from script as soon as it get's started and show 'Processing your request' as result for `success`:

```
<?php

    ob_end_clean();                    // discard everything
    header("Connection: close");       // send Connection close
    ignore_user_abort(true);           // ignore user abort
    set_time_limit(0);                 // no time limit
    ini_set("memory_limit","200M");    // setup a memory usage needed
    ob_start();                        // start output buffer

    header("Content-Length: 0");       // send lenght 0
    ob_end_flush();                    // end and flush
    flush();

    // continue your script
```

Your script will continue to run while you receive a success answer from it.

Comment: Yeah, I know there is always one return value. You are right in guessing what I want but problem is that I am not that good at PHP. I even don't know what your code does. I only know to play with variables and control structures right now in PHP. Can it be little simpler?

Comment: This is just needed to return to ajax that data was received. Just prepend it to your php script.

Comment: Then any way to get informed client side when script server side has finished running?

Comment: If I prepend this to my script and echo something, the return value is blank. Removing it again returns value successfully but after 2 seconds and that is what I want to eliminate. I want to tell user quickly (instantly) not to worry, the action you performed is done.

Comment: @Heart So why not use the classic way, show to user message before you send your ajax request? If finally the ajax request failed, just apologies  :)

Comment: @roasted I think for me it is good to keep the classic way. :) If request fails, a red div will be displayed and Bam! User will have to hit that button again. :/

Answer (score 0):

You might use it like this

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   context: document.body
   }).done(function() {
   $(this).addClass("done");
   });
```

For more details please check following link

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/